# Deleting a Mac Partition on a drive that has bootcamp?

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition, windows

I have the following setup and am looking for a solution to delete a partition on the drive that has bootcamp. Below is my system setup -

Primary SSD: Contains mac OS Sierra. Bootable - I boot from this drive.

Secondary SSD (in place of Optical Drive): Windows 7 Bootable (100GB) + Empty Mac Partition (130 GB) + Another Empty Mac Partition (26 GB).

I would like to delete the partition that has 26GB and 1) merge it with my Windows 7 Partition OR 2) merge it with my 130GB Partition.

I have tried to merge it with my Windows 7 Partition which is when i created the 26GB partition using Disk Utility. I realized that made my Windows 7 partition unbootable before i could merge the 26GB GB to it. I was able to recover it by recreating the MBR, but now the 26GB partition still remains. Does anybody have any ideas as to how to add this to windows partition? Or if that involves reinstalling windows i could just let go all the hassle and add it back to my 130 GB partition. Either solution works for me. The key thing is I don't want to corrupt my boot config again.

Any advise would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please add the output of `diskutil list`, `sudo gpt show -r diskX` and `sudo fdisk diskX` with diskX: disk ident of the sec. SSD.

Answer (score 1):

From within OSX you should be able to delete both the empty mac partitions, then create a new one, all using Disk Utility.

Here's a good guide: https://www.lifewire.com/resize-mac-disk-utility-volume-os-x-el-capital-later-3573395

Given that both partitions are empty there's no risk of data loss here. Just wipe them both out and create one large one.

Comment: when i created the 26GB Partition it made my windows 7 partition unbootable. I had repair the MBR for it to show up again as a bootable drive. Are you sure this will work?